# What responsibility I have by letting customers take payments from their clients on my system

Tags: internet, software, payment

I want to let users add their Stripe, Braintree or other payment processors API keys to my system and then let them send links to their clients where they can pay for services or whatever they are asking for.

Question is how much responsibility/liability I have taking into account I will only provide a system to connect their payment processor's accounts. I will never receive money from end-users. But domain, where they will be making payments, is mine.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 3):

You have two downvoted answers here. One of them is actually correct, one is nonsense. Question: Which one?

Answer: Doesn't matter. If you provide this service without getting advice from a competent lawyer first, your risk is much too high. Making the wrong decision (either giving up on a good business idea without reason, or providing a banking service without license) will cost you much much more than paying a lawyer for advice.

Answer (score -1):

### Sounds like you’re providing a (limited) banking service

If you are, you will need a financial services licence and to comply with all relevant rules such as reporting and anti-money laundering.

Comment: No offense, but Google stripe. Stripe is the banking service, not him.

Comment: Given two opinions, one who says it sounds like he's providing a banking service, one who says he doesn't, the risk of doing this is much too high to do it without asking a lawyer.

Comment: How does this address the question of his liability?

Answer (score -2):

You couldn't knowingly allow someone to do anything illegal on your site, but if you don't condone it and they do it, it's not your fault.

People do illegal things on plenty of popular websites and it's not the fault of the website. The same applies to you.

Comment: There are a significant number of court cases that say otherwise.